# How to retrieve a particular session value in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I would set a session value in codeigniter

```
$sess_array = array(
'id' => $row->Login_Id,
'username' => $row->Login_Name,
'postid'=> $row->Fk_Post_Id,
 );
$CI->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
```

Then how to retrieve a particular (say - id) session value . I tried these

```
$createdby=$this->session->userdata('id');
$createdby=$this->session->userdata($logged_in['id']);
```

but fails.

Comment: can you get value in `$_SESSION['logged_in']['id']`...?

Comment: it says like this  - Undefined variable: _SESSION

Comment: Then simple ... you dont have session start at beginning .. see my edited code

Comment: I start session when logins.thanks dreamcoder ,for your quick and kind reply . ...

Comment: thaks all for helping me..

Comment: Though it is an old question, It worked for me!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the array syntax for this. Like,

```
$this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id'];
```

Comment: Though it is an old answer, It worked for me!

Answer (score 5):

set it like this

```
$sess_array = array(
                    'id'        =>  $row->Login_Id,
                    'username'  =>  $row->Login_Name,
                    'postid'    =>  $row->Fk_Post_Id,
                );

$CI->session->set_userdata($sess_array);
```

To retrieve

```
$createdby  =   $this->session->userdata('id');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$createdby = $this->session->userdata(logged_in['id']);
```

or

```
$createdby = echo $_SESSION[logged_in['id']];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$sess_array = array(
'id' => $row->Login_Id,
'username' => $row->Login_Name,
'postid'=> $row->Fk_Post_Id,
 );
$CI->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
```

then

```
$logged_in = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
$createdby = $logged_in['id'];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Session write process. session content could be dynamic value
$logged_in = [
'id'=> 1,
'name'=> 'test'
]; 

Particular Session retrieve process.


    $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id'];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$pdata = array(
                'id'        =>  $row->Login_Id,
                'username'  =>  $row->Login_Name,
               );  // pass ur data in the array

$this->session->set_userdata('session_data', $pdata); //Sets the session


$pdata = $this->session->userdata('session_data'); //Retrive ur session

$pdata['id'] will give u the corresponding id
```

Answer (score 1):

In newer version, you can simply use

```
$this->session->username
$this->session->id
$this->session->postid
```